# What is the codomain of the exponential function?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Do we have

1. $\exp:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$; or
2. $\exp:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$?

Option 1 seems to be common but seems to have the problem that $\exp$ wouldn't be the inverse of $\ln:\mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R $ ?

Comment: Both options have advantages and disadvantages but in every situation you can just make your choice.

Comment: @drhab: What are some disadvantages of option 2?

Comment: Well, for instance if $g:\mathbb R\to Y$ denotes a function then in the second case composition $g\circ\mathsf{exp}$ is formally not well defined because domain of $g$ does not coincide with codomain of $\mathsf{exp}$. This has impact if we look at functions as morphisms in category $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: @drhab: I thought that for the composition $g \circ \exp$ to be well defined, we just need the range of $\exp$ to be a subset of the domain of $g$? Which is the case here ($\mathbb R^+ \subseteq \mathbb R$)?

Comment: There are areas (e.g. categories) where more is demanded. In the case you mention we are then dealing with composition $g\circ\iota\circ\mathsf{exp}$ where $\iota:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$ denotes the inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The codomain may be any set that contains the positive real numbers. The range of course is the set of all positive reals, provided the domain is restricted to only the real numbers.